# HP dl360 gen7 connected to internet but can't see the lan

Tags: linux, local-area-network

My HP 360 gen7 computer had been running Fedora for years but yesterday after(during dnf update) a kernel update, it has started acting weird. It is the same kind of behavior that started during that update. It lost access to the lan. After the reboot, it sometimes connects to the lan for a  few seconds and then something happens. it does get ip addresses on it NICs. While it can't see the lan (ping, mount, ssh etc), it can access the internet without any issue. Nothing has changed as far as the network/lan topology is concerned. All the computer are connected to the router which is connected to the modem from the ISP.

If a terminal with ping command is left on on another computer, then it shows up connected to the lan for a few seconds while booting. The ping output looks like given below:

```
 From acer17 (192.168.27.166) icmp_seq=1161 Destination Host Unreachable
From acer17 (192.168.27.166) icmp_seq=1162 Destination Host Unreachable
From acer17 (192.168.27.166) icmp_seq=1163 Destination Host Unreachable
From acer17 (192.168.27.166) icmp_seq=1164 Destination Host Unreachable
From acer17 (192.168.27.166) icmp_seq=1165 Destination Host Unreachable
From acer17 (192.168.27.166) icmp_seq=1166 Destination Host Unreachable
64 bytes from dl360 (192.168.27.2): icmp_seq=3 ttl=64 time=0.249 ms
64 bytes from dl360 (192.168.27.2): icmp_seq=4 ttl=64 time=0.378 ms
64 bytes from dl360 (192.168.27.2): icmp_seq=5 ttl=64 time=0.333 ms
...........................
From acer17 (192.168.27.166) icmp_seq=1172 Destination Host Unreachable
From acer17 (192.168.27.166) icmp_seq=1173 Destination Host Unreachable
From acer17 (192.168.27.166) icmp_seq=1174 Destination Host Unreachable
From acer17 (192.168.27.166) icmp_seq=1175 Destination Host Unreachable
From acer17 (192.168.27.166) icmp_seq=1176 Destination Host Unreachable
```

Same behavior is visible from the boot messages, where it connects to some network drives and then loses the connectivity to LAN while trying to read from them in starting subsequent services etc.

Everything else on the network is working just fine. Tried swapping other NIC ports as well as router ports but behavior is the same.
As I mentioned before access to internet is working just fine so anything external can be accessed from it (running dnf update etc. works). I tried booting with previous kernel versions but it is the same behavior.

I'll really appreciate if someone can point me in a direction to resolve this issue as this is my work horse doing the heavy lifting.

As the  logs did not provide any useful info. I booted using Fedora 37 live usb  which might shed some light into the weird behavior. First of all, the bios was not detecting usb key if I select USB as first entry in boot order.Only time it recognized it if I disable the raid and keep the standard boot order(cd rom, floppy, usb, hd, nic). I was able to install fedora on to another usb key ans system booted fine a few times but not it fails to recognize the usb again. Last night, I tried booting with Fedora 38 liveusb but after claiming to not find any usb, it randomly recognized it once and gave the boot options but the boot process failed with kernel panic.  So  far it seems the bios/boot loader is acting up as it does not honor its own settings. Oh, and the older disks in th raid seem to be gone and didnt show up in the listing when system was booted(with raid disabled but controller enabled) using fedora 37 while all other external drives did show up normal.

Comment: Does your logs show anything? What does `ip a` show for instance? `dmesg`? `iptables-save`?

Comment: Added more info with live usb reboot. The network works fine but the boot process itself is flaky.